# Magento 2 How to add barcode to shipment PDF

Tags: magento2, pdf, shipment, barcode

I want to add **barcode** of **Tracking Number** in to my shipment **PDF** without use of any third party extenssion.

Can any one help me to how to generate barcode in to **PDF** in magento 2, is there any default magento function to achieve this things.

Any help would be Appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you get any solution for it ?

Comment: Yes below solution is working for me. for more reference check this link https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.barcode.creation.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Zend library Zend_Barcode, see below a cose snippet I have used in the past.

```
$barcodeConfig = [
                'drawText' => false,
                'barThickWidth'=>'1',
                'barHeight'=>'30',
                'orientation' => 0,
                'text' => $shipment->getTrackingNumber()
            ];
            $rendererConfig = [
                'leftOffset' => $left,
                'topOffset' => $top
            ];
            $renderer = \Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'pdf', $barcodeConfig, $rendererConfig)->setResource($this->_getPdf(), 0);
            $renderer->draw();
```

Comment: when i scan barcode it is display value `code128` not display tracking number.

Comment: How to check if this bar-code  value is true or false?

Comment: See https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.barcode.creation.html

Comment: how to create on magento 2.3 version ?

Comment: I don't believe this works on any Magento 2 version as Zend_Barcode is not a anymore available within the ootb libraries